# Simple Calendar on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, rubygems

I am building a trip app on Rails and I've run into this problem trying to use simple_calendar gem:
My calendar always starts in October (this month), but I would like it to start according to the date I have in my tables.
My index.html.erb:

```html
<%= month_calendar(attribute: :start_date, end_attribute: :end_date) do |date| %>
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><%= date.day %></h5>
          <% @logged_in_user.trips do |trip| %>
    <%= @trip_activities = trip.activities %></p>
 <% @trip_activities.each do |activity| %>
<!-- <%= activity_date = (activity.start_date).to_s %>
<%= activity_datetime = activity_date[0..9].to_datetime %> -->
  <% if date === activity_datetime %>

    <p class="card-text"><%= activity.time%>: <%= activity.description%></p>


<% end %>
<% end %>
    <% end %>
    <a href="#" class="card-link"> <%= link_to '+ activities', new_activity_path  %> </a>
  </div>
</div>
    <% end %>
```

My controller:

```html
  def index
    @logged_in_user = User.find_by :id => session[:user_id]
    @this_trip = Trip.find params[:id]
  end
```

My table:

```html
gabe_trip = Trip.create(destination: 'Australia', start_date: '2019-10-22 01:00:00 UTC', num_of_days: 20, user_id: gabe.id)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Cheers,

Comment: The docs say, "The first parameter is a symbol that looks up the current date in params. If no date is found, it will use the current date." Do you have `:start_date` in `params`?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with `fullCalendar`, which is a different plugin. Please check tag descriptions before you use them. If you tag your questions accurately, more people with the relevant skills and interests will see them. If you use irrelevant tags, it will just irritate others who find a question which is not interesting to them. I removed it for you this time. Thanks.

Comment: @jvillian it worked!! thanks :)
I added to my controller:    params[:start_date] = this_trip.start_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use start_date as an argument.  For example, if your_date is "Oct 1, 2023"

```
    <%= month_calendar(start_date: Date.parse(your_date)) do |date| %>
      <%= date.day %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> The first parameter is a symbol that looks up the current date in params. If no date is found, it will use the current date.

Do you have `:start_date` in params? If not, you could add `start_date` to your `params`.